# Easy XPathNavigator GetAttribute

Tags: c#, xml, xpathnavigator

Just getting started here with my first take at `XPathNavigator`.

This is my simple xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<theroot>
    <thisnode>
        <thiselement visible="true" dosomething="false"/>
        <another closed node />
    </thisnode>

</theroot>
```

Now, I am using the `CommonLibrary.NET` library to help me a little:

```
    public static XmlDocument theXML = XmlUtils.LoadXMLFromFile(PathToXMLFile);

    const string thexpath = "/theroot/thisnode";

    public static void test() {
        XPathNavigator xpn = theXML.CreateNavigator();
        xpn.Select(thexpath);
        string thisstring = xpn.GetAttribute("visible","");
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(thisstring);
    }
```

Problem is that it can't find the attribute.  I've looked through the documentation at MSDN for this, but can't make much sense of what's happening.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two problems here are:

(1) Your path is selecting the `thisnode` element, but the `thiselement` element is the one with the attributes and
(2) `.Select()` does not change the location of the `XPathNavigator`. It returns an `XPathNodeIterator` with the matches.

Try this:

```
public static XmlDocument theXML = XmlUtils.LoadXMLFromFile(PathToXMLFile);

const string thexpath = "/theroot/thisnode/thiselement";

public static void test() {
    XPathNavigator xpn = theXML.CreateNavigator();
    XPathNavigator thisEl = xpn.SelectSingleNode(thexpath);
    string thisstring = xpn.GetAttribute("visible","");
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(thisstring);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's it.  I was neglecting to capture the node into a second `XPathNavigator` - I suppose I thought it worked differently.  I also found this link, which presents it in an easy fashion too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308118/c-sharp-get-attribute-values-from-matching-xml-nodes-using-xpath-query?rq=1

Comment: @user3240414 tried to ask the following question by editing my answer (please don't do that): _What will be the output for the statement `string thisstring = xpn.GetAttribute("visible","");
 Console.WriteLine(thisstring);`_ The output should be `true` in this case.

Answer (score 7):

You can select a attribute on an element using xpath like this (An alternative to the accepted answer above):

```
public static XmlDocument theXML = XmlUtils.LoadXMLFromFile(PathToXMLFile);

const string thexpath = "/theroot/thisnode/thiselement/@visible";

public static void test() {
    XPathNavigator xpn = theXML.CreateNavigator();
    XPathNavigator thisAttrib = xpn.SelectSingleNode(thexpath);
    string thisstring = thisAttrib.Value;
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(thisstring);
}
```