# How to read xml data in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to read an xml and display its data in a form. Following is the code generated with the form.  If I want to just display "Hello World" from a tab value in XML, where should I put the code in the C# code generated by the VB form, if my Xml schema (test.xml)is as below.

```
   <tab>
        <message>Hello World</Message>
   </tab>
```

Following is the code generated by the form. I included System.Xml to read the Xml file. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace xmldatatest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("C:\\test.xml");
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: *VB C#* is not a language, and we're not a code writing service. What code have you written so far to attempt to do this yourself? What specific problem are you having with that code? Please [edit] your question to include the code you've tried, explain how it doesn't work as it should, and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll be happy to try and help.

Comment: [so] have a lot of resources to help you read the XML, like this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656686/how-to-read-xml-data-using-c-sharp?rq=1) and this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c?rq=1)

Comment: @Ken White: My apologies. I changed my question and the simple code I have.

Comment: @ Alex: Thank you. Resource links you provided answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your XML File to be valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<tab>
    <message>Hello World</message>
</tab>
```

C# code should be like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("C:\\test.xml");

        var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/tab/message");

        // Gets "Hello World"
        var message = node.InnerText;

        // you can do whatever with the message now...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, I got the program to out put the text stored in "message" variable. Thank you

Comment: @shapedworld glad to hear that you got it working. If this is the answer then please mark it as answer. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The XML example you supplied is not valid:

```
<tab>
     <message>Hello World</Message>
</tab>
```

Your *message* tag starts with this `<message>` but ends with this `</Message>`.

Comment: Hi Jussij, I only added schema but didn't included the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> part in my question. to keep the question short. I'll include it next time. Thanks